# Mocking file handles

Tags: python, unit-testing

[There's a couple of stack overflow posts out there talking about mocking the open call in Python.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166633/mocking-file-objects-or-iterables-in-python) That's great but it doesn't really help me if a function takes in a file handle or stream object instead of a file path.

One solution I've been using up until now has been `cStringIO` objects. I've run into a problem, however.

If I want to test if I'm logging the file name correctly on some sort of failure (say if the file / stream is empty and you expect some kind of data)

```
cStringIO
fd = cStringIO("")
fd.name = "testing/path" # Throws an AttributeError
```

I can't set the name attribute since `cStringIO` and `StringIO` are slotted classes.

If switch over to using `open_mock`

```
with mock.patch('__main__.open', mock.mock_open(read_data=''), create=True) as m:
```

I run into

```
AttributeError: Mock object has no attribute 'tell'
```

At this point it feels like I have to use temp files but I'd like to avoid actually calling out to the file system if possible.

**How do you test functions that take in file handles without having to create actual files on a file system?**

Comment: Works fine for me: http://pastebin.com/6QkKxdER, Could you show your function under the test?

Comment: Ah, you explicitly set the `tell` attribute. That also worked for me. You should post that as an answer. I ended up making my own class that inherited from StringIO and object. I think your answer is might be cleaner than the one I ended up using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `tell` attribute explicitly for the mock object using [`Mock.return_value`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.return_value):

```
import mock

def function_under_test(f):
    f.tell()  # => 0
    f.read()
    f.tell()  # => 0
    return f.name

with mock.patch('__main__.open', mock.mock_open(read_data=''), create=True) as m:
    with open('/tmp/1') as f:
        f.name = '/tmp/1'
        f.tell.return_value = 0
        assert function_under_test(f) == '/tmp/1'
```

Answer (score 0):

I went down the path of creating a class that inherited from StringIO. It took me more time than I want to admit to figure out that in Python2.7 StringIO is an old style class.

```
class MockFile(StringIO, object):
    """This is a work around for the fact that StringIO is a slotted class and
    doesn't have a name attribute.
    """
    name = None
    def __init__(self, name, buffer_ = None):
        super(MockFile, self).__init__(buffer_)
        self.name = name
```