# mock paramiko.SSHClient().exec_command()

Tags: python, mocking, paramiko

I need mock execution of some remote command via ssh.exec_command() 
It returns tuple (stdin, stdout, stderr) as paramiko.ChanelFile object.

So, I have output of command as string (which I want, exec_command() to return) and the question how to create ChanelFile object with my output string.

Pseudo code:

```python
    def send_command(self, cmd)
        self.client.connect(hostname=self.host,
                            username=self.user,
                            password=self.password,
                            timeout=self.timeout)
        stdin, stdout, stderr = self.client.exec_command(cmd)

        return stdin, stdout, stderr

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        stdin, stdout, stderr = report.send_command('ls -la')
        resp = stdout.read().strip()
```

So I need create stout to be able run read() method on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/8168742/5512755
A MagicMock works here too.

```
stdout = mock.MagicMock()
stdout.read().strip.return_value = "file1\nfile2\nfile3\n"
```

will do the trick.